# Содержит ли переменная / if

Tags: php, if

Доброе время суток. Можно ли сделать конструкцию if так, что бы если $tts **содержит** "ЛМ" выводить один текст, а если не содержит то другой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tts = 'текст';
$find = "ЛМ";
$pos = strripos($tts, $find);
if ($pos === false) {
//не нашли
} else {
//нашли
}
```

Это если я вас правильно понял

Comment: Правильно поняли, но вместо $needle нужно было $find :)

Comment: @Manitikyl, `mb_strripos()` тогда уж. `strpos` и аналоги проверяют побайтовое совпадение, регистр скорее всего меняется просто за счет конвертации по таблице ASCII-символов и ничего дельного не выйдет.